# Hide table row when cell is empty

Tags: css

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to find an answer to, but I can't imagine it's not possible.

I have a table with two columns: the left column contains a label, the right side contains a value. However, the value can be empty. The label is fixed text.

What I want is to hide the entire row if the right cell of the row (the value) is empty.

For example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="label">number of users:</td>
   <td class="value">8</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="label">total number of people:</td>
  <td class="value"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Since the last row does not contain a value, I want the entire row to be hidden.

I can hide the cell using td:empty, but that's not enough. I tried to work around this by setting the height of the row to 0px and make it expand when the 'value'-cell is shown, but I can't get that to work either since the label cell already expands the row.

Anyone knows how I can tackle this problem using just HTML/CSS?

Comment: i am afraid you need to use `javascript` for this.

Comment: The best solution would be JQuery.

Comment: You might need to resort to javascript (jQuery perhaps) to find if there is a value in td, and if not then to find nearest parent, and hide it. Are you importing jQuery?

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. The webpage is loaded into an external application which does not support jQuery or Javascript. The Javascript code worked in IE, but as soon as I imported it in the application it did not work anymore. I also tried executing some trivial Javascript functions but those didn't work either so I'm pretty sure this application doesn't "do" Javascript. I guess we have to live with empty values until the software supplier changes the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While JavaScript is necessary to solve this problem, jQuery is, by no means, a requirement. Using the DOM, one can achieve this with the following:

```
function hideParentsOf(cssSelector) {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
    if (elems.length) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function (el) {
            el.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
}

hideParentsOf('td:empty');
```

```js
function hideParentsOf(cssSelector) {
  // cssSelector: String,
  //              a string representing a CSS selector,
  //              such as 'td:empty' in this case.

  // retrieving a NodeList of elements matching the supplied selector:
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);

  // if any elements were found:
  if (elems.length) {
    // iterating over the array-like NodeList with Array.forEach():
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
      // el is the current array-element (or NodeList-element in
      // this instance).
      // here we find the parentNode, and set its 'display' to 'none':
      el.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
}

hideParentsOf('td:empty');
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">number of users:</td>
    <td class="value">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">total number of people:</td>
    <td class="value"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:empty` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).

Comment: Thanks, this worked in IE, but unfortunately not in the external application that is using this webpage.

Comment: Unfortunately, without knowing more about the 'external application' I'm not sure I can provide further help. Though it may be the (relatively modern) JavaScript methods I've used. That application should, probably, have been mentioned in the question itself, though.

Answer (score 4):

There's no parent selector in css, so you can't do this with css.

You may use jQuery:

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(:empty)){
     $(this).closest('tr').hide();
  }
});
```

Or in shorter form,

```
$('tr:has("td:empty")').hide();
```

See the docs: [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/), [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/),[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [each](http://api.jquery.com/each)

Comment: I've removed the jQuery tag from the question, since while JavaScript is necessary to provide an answer it's presumptive to specify a library of *your* choice, without the approval of, or confirmation from, the OP.

Comment: I don't have access to jQuery in my situation, so I can't use this code. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML/CSS solution exists if you don't mind throwing out `<table>` `<tr>` and `<td>`. You can get the same end result with CSS - including still rendering like a table:

CSS:

```
/* hide if empty */
.hideIfEmpty:empty { display: none; }

/* label style */
.hideIfEmpty::before { font-weight:bold; }

/* labels */
.l_numberofusers::before { content:"Number of users: "; } 
.l_numberofpeople::before { content: "Number of people:"; }
.l_numberofdogs::before { content: "Number of dogs:" }

/* table like rows/cells */
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }
```

HTML

```
<!-- if the div.hideIfEmpty is empty, it'll be hidden; 
     labels come from CSS -->

<div class="table">
  <div class="row hideIfEmpty l_numberofusers"><span class="cell">8</span></div>
  <div class="row hideIfEmpty l_numberofpeople"><span class="cell">12</span></div>
  <div class="row hideIfEmpty l_numberofdogs"></div>
</div>
```

The caveat is that your `<div>` has to be empty to hide the row, and values in the `<div>` *must* have a class `.cell` applied to them.

Result:

```
Number of users:           8
Number of people:          12
```

This will make your CSS very long if you have many labels/rows since you have to have one rule for every row to populate the label.